# How to reload a script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I’m new here so please bear with me.  I’m using jQuery infinite-scroll to load content when scrolling. While this work fine, this content will change with user inputs using ajax. What I want to do is to reload/refresh infinite scroll code on ajax content load.

This is infinite-scroll code

Plugin: https://infinite-scroll.com/

```
$('#content').infiniteScroll({
  // options
  path: '#page-nav a',
  append: '.post',
  history: false,
  status: '.page-load-status',
});
```

This is my ajax code to reload content.

```
$("#searchContent :input").change(function() {  
   var formData = {
      'title' : $('input[name=title]:checked').val(),
      'tags' : $('input[name=tags]').val()
   };
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get_content.php",
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(json) {
         $("#content").html(json.content); 
      }
   });
});
```

All I want to do is reload infinity scroll code when executing ajax post function. Can anyone point me out how to achieve this? appreciate your time.

Comment: call plugin again after you change the content in `success`

Comment: @charlietfl wont this will conflict with the already loaded code?

Comment: Have a closer look at the documentation, it actually doesn't require you include your own ajax functions, and calling jQuery's html() function means you won't be using infinate scroll but just replacing the page you see so I'd avoid that. If nobody replies before I get home tonight I'll include a proper example.

Comment: Kodaloid thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-initiate plugin for new DOM:

```
$("#searchContent :input").change(function() {
  var formData = {
    'title': $('input[name=title]:checked').val(),
    'tags': $('input[name=tags]').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_content.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      $("#content")
        .html(json.content)
        .infiniteScroll({
        // options
          path: '#page-nav a',
          append: '.post',
          history: false,
          status: '.page-load-status',
      });
    }
  });
});
```

---

*Side notes*

Usually infinite scroll means auto-page without clicking pagination. But you are just removing old content and adding new one instead of appending to existing elements. What exactly you are trying to do?

Try `$('form').serialize()` instead of `var formData = {}`

You are adding elements directly from json response. Maybe try some template where you just replace values?

Comment: im getting an error `TypeError: o._init is not a function`